# exercise in Paul Larson's book "The Stationary Tower", wondering if it is stated correctly

Tags: logic, set-theory

This question refers to Exercise 1.1.7 in Paul Larson's book "The Stationary Tower".

"Show that if $M$ and $N$ are transitive models of ZFC and $j:M \rightarrow N$ is a non-trivial $\Sigma_0$-elementary embedding (i.e. preserving the $\in$-relation) with $N\subset M$, then $j$ is not the identity on the ordinals."

I thought that usually a $\Sigma_0$-elementary embedding would mean that we should have $M \models \phi(x_1, x_2 \ldots x_n)$ iff $N \models \phi(j(x_1), j(x_2), \ldots j(x_n))$ for all $\Sigma_0$ formulas $\phi$ where that means that $\phi$ may have bounded quantifiers. I am not able to see how this is equivalent to "preserving the $\in$-relation" even on the additional assumption that $N\subset M$, nor how to do the exercise on the assumption that "$\Sigma_0$-elementary embedding" just means "preserving the $\in$-relation".

Comment: Have you tried showing by induction on the structure of the formula that preserving the $\in$ relation would be enough to get $\Sigma_0$ elementarity?

Comment: Yes, the induction step works for bounded existential quantifiers but not for bounded universal quantifiers. I am now pretty sure that the exercise must be stated incorrectly, that is, I think that I can show that "preserving the $\in$-relation" is not enough for the desired conclusion.

Comment: Yes, this was a mistake. There are more. See the errata list posted at the bottom of the page here: http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/papers.html